# UIWebDocumentView : No info in iOS Library

Tags: iphone, pdf

I cant fing any documentation regading `UIWebDocumentView` in iOS Library .
Any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's a private API class, a.k.a. don't use it or your app will be rejected by AppStore.

Comment: Dear @Art ,can u please provide some useful link into apple docs supporting your answer

Comment: The fact that it is not present in the iOS documentation tells you that it is a private API.

In addition, no header is available; another clue that it is a private API.

The only place it appears is as a `@class` marker in UITextView.

Yes, it's weird that type-ahead finds it -- that's probably a bug.  But it's a private API (as of iOS6); best not to use it until it's announced and documented.